# How to decrease size of backround header img in html/css?

Tags: html, css

So I want to decrease the size of the img on the header so it looks cleaner and a more sharp img , however i am unsure how to do it?

**Here is the code**

**CSS:**

```
.header {
  background: #000000 url (C:/website/logo final.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 80px 60px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <header>
   <div id="header" align="center">
   <img name="Antique Picture" src="C:\website\logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="100%" height="100%">
 </header>
```

all help would be rly appreciated 
thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Ideally more code would be best, but meanwhile, here's an example with a demo image:

- `url` & `()` should have no space in between, like this: `background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat;`.
- If you wish to tweak image size you can use `width` & `height` properties.
- In this scenario original image size is `100 x 100px` set to `80 x 60px`.

```css
.header {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS code as below:

```
.header {
      background-image:url ("xyz.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      width:100%;
      height:300px;
}
```

Comment: had no effect let me send a ss of the site   https://gyazo.com/d7066a796ba273c471273398527edcee

Comment: @willtcrook please add some html indicating header in html in your question

Answer (score 1):

Apply width 100% to your header image in style sheet, and do not give height.
I will take width of header div and will adjust height automatically.

Your code should look like below:

```
.header {
    background: #000000 url (C:/website/logo final.svg) no-repeat;
    background-width: 100%;
 }
```